# Weka numeric class multilayer perceptron

Tags: weka

i was using the weka interface to do some classification using the MultilayerPerceptron.

My class is numeric and i am trying now to do the classification from command line... so i can leave the computer doing the simulation using a lot of files.

I was trying to use the

```
java -classpath weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t ~/Desktop/arff/3x3-noextra.arff -W weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -- -L 0.4 -M 0.5 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a
```

Command as a test, but because my class is numeric i get the:

```
weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize: Cannot handle numeric class!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:954)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1110)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1023)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
    at weka.filters.Filter.testInputFormat(Filter.java:434)
    at weka.filters.Filter.setInputFormat(Filter.java:452)
    at weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize.setInputFormat(Discretize.java:286)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.buildClassifier(FilteredClassifier.java:389)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1149)
    at weka.classifiers.Classifier.runClassifier(Classifier.java:315)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.main(FilteredClassifier.java:478)
```

Error,

On the interface it is automatic, i dont need to handle nothing, how can i do that using the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some stupid things, i just needed the  multilayerperceptron.

I solved that with:

```
java -classpath weka.jar  weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron  -L 0.3 -M 0.5 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a
```

Just calling the multilayer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just taking a wild guess here:

FilteredClassifier has an -F parameter by default which isn't defined in your command line.  perhaps adding this parameter with the filter parameters as required by your model will overcome the Discretize error that was raised in Weka.

Hope this Helps!